# Pascal triangle multiple errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have this code to print pascal triangle with N lines (N represents the user input of how many lines they want). I have the format needed, but I don't know how to make the code work.

I'm new to python and programming in general, and really struggling with `functions`. I don't know how to write arguments for functions, and how to pass them properly.

the problems is from the second function onwards (`def pascal_triangle_tostring()`). I can get the input and generate the list. But from here I'm not sure what to do.

```
#should take user input and validates it
def get_triangle_size():
    while True:
        numberOfRows = input("Enter the no. of rows: ")
        try:
            numberOfRows = int(numberOfRows)
        except ValueError:
             print("N must be an integer")
             continue
        if numberOfRows <= 0:
            print("N must be at least 1")
            continue
        break
    return (numberOfRows)

#Should generate Pascals triangle (shaped like a ladder)
def generate_pascal_triangle():
    n = get_triangle_size()
    if n == 1:
        triangle = [[1]]
    elif n == 2:
        triangle = [[1], [1, 1]]
    else:
        triangle = [[1], [1, 1]]
    for i in range(2, n):
        row = [1]
        for j in range(1, i):
            row.append(triangle[i-1][j-1] + triangle[i-1][j])
        row.append(1)
        triangle.append(row)

#should convert the lists of pascal triangle into a string
def pascal_triangle_tostring():
    output = ""
    triangle = get_triangle_size()
    for row in triangle:
        for value in row:
            output += str(value) + "\t"
        output += '\n'

#Main code body should call these functions to print out pascal triangle
print("This program prints a Pascal's triangle with n line")
triangle_size = get_triangle_size()
pascal_triangle = generate_pascal_triangle()
print("Pascal’s triangle with %d lines:\n" % triangle_size)
print(pascal_triangle_tostring(pascal_triangle))
```

Comment: first thing I notice is that You raise a `ValueError` which pretty much is catcthed instantly by the excpet statement so You should remove the `raise ValueError` line since it does more bad than good

Comment: @Matiiss Oh yes that's right. I had a while loop that would check the user input to be a positive integer. I forgot to remove the ```raise ValueError``` as I was just playing with the code to see what it does. thank you. I'll edit the code to fix this

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  You've dumped about 35 lines of code without giving us any idea of what's wrong.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: @Prune The very generous person who answered my question understood what I was trying to say. And I have tried to explain what is wrong in saying the code doesn't work. I tried debugging and searching google, but I did not find a solution that I could understand and implement. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now I improved Your code so now it seems to work, so I know You have questions so please ask them. also You should really learn about `function arguments` and `f strings` in python

```
#should take user input and validates it
def get_triangle_size():
    # while True:
    numberOfRows = input("Enter the no. of rows: ")
    try:
        numberOfRows = int(numberOfRows)
    except ValueError:
        print("N must be an integer")

    if numberOfRows <= 0:
        print("N must be at least 1")

    return numberOfRows

#Should generate Pascals triangle (shaped like a ladder)
def generate_pascal_triangle(n):
    if n == 1:
        triangle = [[1]]
    elif n == 2:
        triangle = [[1], [1, 1]]
    else:
        triangle = [[1], [1, 1]]
    for i in range(2, n):
        row = [1]
        for j in range(1, i):
            row.append(triangle[i-1][j-1] + triangle[i-1][j])
        row.append(1)
        triangle.append(row)
    return triangle

#should convert the lists of pascal triangle into a string
def pascal_triangle_tostring(triangle):
    output = ""
    for row in triangle:
        for value in row:
            output += str(value) + "\t"
        output += '\n'
    return output

#Main code body should call these functions to print out pascal triangle
print("This program prints a Pascal's triangle with n line")
triangle_size = get_triangle_size()
pascal_triangle = generate_pascal_triangle(triangle_size)
print("Pascal’s triangle with %d lines:\n" % triangle_size)
print(pascal_triangle_tostring(pascal_triangle))
```

Comment: Thank you so so so very much. I have been reading on ```function arguments``` I don't seem to get it quick enough. I will continue reading and study the code you provided to understand it better. Again thank you so much

Comment: @MANNY sure, but it will also be useful to learn `f strings` as they are very great for string formatting (dont have to learn anything complex just the basics) and again if You have questions just ask and I will try to answer them

Comment: I will sure do look it up and learn it (```f strings```). I appreciate your help 